# ActiveRecord: Query with condition on belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table `transaction` and table `user`.

```
transactions
   id
   user_id
users
   id
   user_role
```

Here is class `Transaction`:

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :user
end
```

Now, I want to query all transactions made by user with role = 2. My query will be:

```
SaleTransaction.includes(:user).where(user: {user_role: 2}).all
```

But I meet this error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing
>   FROM-clause entry for table "user"

My question is: How can I query on `belongs_to` association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify table name in where clause. Try

`SaleTransaction.includes(:user).where(users: {user_role: 2}).all`

But you can do, better than that. If user had a `scope` inside the model, you could something like this

```
class User
   scope :second_user_role
end


SaleTransaction.joins(:user).merge(user.second_user_role).all
```

Comment: thanks. it works :D and I have learned 1 point from your post :D

Comment: @TrầnKimDự Such query is not optimized. What it does is executing 2 queries and takes intersection of them. You shouldn't use merge. You need to go just with a plain where clause.

Comment: @AntonTkachov No, it doesn't. Here is the produced sql `SaleTransaction Load (5.3ms)  SELECT  "sale_transactions".* FROM "sale_transactions" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "sale_transactions"."user_id" WHERE "users"."user_role" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_role", "2"], ["LIMIT", 11]]`

Answer (score 2):

`:joins` will just joins the tables and brings selected fields in return. if you call associations on joins query result, it will fire database queries again

`:includes` will eager load the included associations and add them in memory. `:includes` loads all the included tables attributes. If you call associations on include query result, it will not fire any queries

What you need to do is:

```
SaleTransaction.joins(:user).where("users.user_role = 2")
```

Comment: I have used your query but I meet same exception: "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "user"

Comment: @TrầnKimDự Updated my post

Comment: thanks. it works. I thinks your solution is similar with @Nikita's solution. But I think using hash syntax will be better. For example: `SaleTransaction.joins(:user).where(users: {user_role: 2})`

Comment: Yes, hash syntax is better for sure